# Uniqueness of a limit from a general topological space to a Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology

I read a proof showing the uniqueness of the limit from a general topological space to a Hausdorff space but don't understand it.

Given a function $f : S \rightarrow T$ from a topological space to a Hausdorff space. First, assume that $a \in S$ is not an isolated point.

Next, $f : S \rightarrow T$ has a limit $b \in T$ if and only if the associated mapping $g : S \rightarrow T$ defined by
$g = f(x)$ for  $x \not= a $ and $g = b$ for  $x = a $ is continuous.

Suppose that $b, c \in T$ are not equal and are both limits of $a$. Then, since $T$ is Hausdorff, there exists disjoint open neightbourhoods $U_b$ and $U_c$ for points $b$ and $c$. Then $g^{-1}(U_b)$ and $g^{-1}(U_c)$ are open neighbourhoods of $a$ in $S$. Then the intesection of $g^{-1}(U_b)$ and $g^{-1}(U_c)$ is also open. Since the intersection only contains $a$, ${a}$ is an open set but since $a$ is not isolated, there is a contradiction and that suffices for the proof.

Why does the intersection contain only $a$?

Comment: Did you mean to say that $\{a\}$ is an open set?

Comment: Yes, when I say $a$ is not isolated I mean $a$ is not an open set.

Comment: Not to be nitpicky, but $a$ is an element of $S$, not a subset of $S$, so it doesn't make sense to say "$a$ is an open set." It is the set containing $a$, $\{a\}$, that would be open.

Answer (score 1):

That argument doesn't make sense, as if $a\in g^{-1}(U_b)\cap g^{-1}(U_c)$, then $g(a)=b\in U_b\cap U_c$. But $U_b$ and $U_c$ are assumed to be disjoint...

Comment: Is there a way to remedy it?

Comment: no just because we suppose somthing false to use the proofing by contraduction. all make sense, just about logic.

Answer (score 0):

because $U_{b}$ and $U_{c}$ are disjoints and $g$ is continuos so $g^{-1}(U_b)$ and $g^{-1}(U_c)$ most be disjoints, so in fact $g^{-1}(U_b)\cap g^{-1}(U_c)=\emptyset$ but $a\in g^{-1}(U_b)$ and $a\in g^{-1}(U_c)$ so $a$ is the only element in $g^{-1}(U_b)\cap g^{-1}(U_c)$.